# Order of \cleardoublepage, \appendix and \phantomsection

Tags: hyperref, appendices

I would like to start the appendices on the first odd numbered page after the bibliography so I've added a `\cleardoublepage` before `\appendix` in my document, structured as shown below. Does the order of the `\cleardoublepage`, `\appendix` and `\phantomsection` commands matter to ensure `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}` always uses the correct page number?

In particular, should `\cleardoublepage` follow `\appendix` and replace `\newpage` in this case, and in general should `\phantomsection` precede or follow `\appendix`?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{bibliografio}

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\input{apendicoj}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\newpage` instruction after `\appendix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends crucially on what the directive `\appendix` does. In the case of the `report` document class (and assuming that no packages which modify `\appendix` have been loaded), this directive (i) resets the `chapter` and `section` counters to 0, (ii) resets the low-level `\chap@app` macro from `\chaptername` to `\appendixname` (which, in turn, is set to the string "Appendix" by default), and (iii) changes the numbering style of chapter-level headers to uppercase-Alphabetic, i.e., to "A", "B", "C", ...

Note that these three tasks are independent of what `\cleardoublepage` does. It thus doesn't really matter, in terms of final outcomes, if `\cleardoublepage` or `\appendix` comes first.

Clearly, though, `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}` must come *after* `\cleardoublepage` and `\appendix`, as otherwise the page numbers shown in the table of contents (among other things) will, in general, be incorrect.